# Retrieve selective items from list

Tags: list, tcl

Is there a way to get items from a list according to some function?

I know there is a way to get items by regular expression by using `lsearch -regexp` but It's not what I need.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Tcl 8.6, you can use the `lmap` command to do this by using `continue` to skip the items you don't want (or `break` to indicate that you've done enough processing):

```
set items {0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10}
set filtered [lmap i $items {if {$i==sqrt($i)**2} {set i} else continue}]
# Result: 0 1 4 9
```

This can be obviously extended into a procedure that takes a lambda term and a list.

```
proc filter {list lambda} {
    lmap i $list {
        if {[apply $lambda $i]} {
            set i
        } else {
            continue
        }
    }
}

set filtered [filter $items {i { expr {$i == sqrt($i)**2} }}]
```

It's possible to do something similar in Tcl 8.5 with `foreach` though you'll need to do more work yourself to build the list of result items with `lappend`…

```
proc filter {list lambda} {
    set result {}
    foreach i $list {
        if {[apply $lambda $i]} {
            lappend result $i
        }
    }
    return $result
}
```

Usage is identical. (Tcl 8.4 and before — now unsupported — don't support the `apply` command.)